# Locating element inside Span tag in Reactjs non angular site using Protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor, webautomation

I need to click on "login" which is inside span tag, code looks like

```
<div data-reactroot>
<div class "ant-dropdown ant-dropdown-placement-bottomRight ant-dropdown-hidden" style="left 632.234px; top 65px;">
<ul class="ant-dropdown-menu ant-dropdown-menu-light ant-dropdown-menu-root ant-dropdown-menu-vertical" role="menu" style="border" 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);">
<li class="ant-dropdown-menu-item" role="menuitem">...</li>
<li class=" ant-dropdown-menu-item-divider"></li>
<li class="ant-dropdown-menu-item" role="menuitem">...</li>
            <span>Login</span>
</li>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDt4z.png

I tried using the code below, it does not work:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.cssContainingText('ant-dropdown-menu-item', 'Login'))
```

I'm getting an error see below:

```
Message: 
Failed: Invalid locator
Stack:
TypeError: Invalid locator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now working i'm tried using the following code below

```
element(by.xpath("//span[. = 'Login']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

`browser.driver.findElement(by.cssContainingText('.ant-dropdown-menu-item', 'Login'))`

In css selectors class need to have `.`.

Edit:
`browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.ant-dropdown-menu-item > span'))`

Comment: i tried adding .. i does not work, i've added more details on the code above

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS testing made more simplifies with [protractor-react-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-react-selector)

protractor-react-selector is a lightweight plugin to help you to locate web elements in your REACT app using props and states.

You need to install the plugin with

```
npm i -D protractor-react-selector
```

Then, you need to add the plugin to the configuration file:

```
exports.config = {
  // ... the rest of your config
  plugins: [
    {
      package: 'protractor-react-selector'
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in a ``` beforeAll`` hook or inside an ```onPrepare``` hook, wait for React to be loaded in your application like:

```
beforeAll(() => {
   await browser.get('http://localhost:3000/myApp')
   await browser.waitForReact()
})
```

Then you can use `element(by.react)` to fetch the react elements.

```
const myElement = element(
  by.react('MyComponent', { someBooleanProp: true }, { someBooleanState: true })
)

myElement.click();
```

For testing the React element, you should not rely on the HTML DOM structure as most of the developers uses material tools that creates dynamic HTML runtime.

To find more example, visit these [tests](https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/protractor-react-selector/blob/master/test/spec.js)

A complete [blog](https://medium.com/@abhinabaghosh.1994/test-your-react-app-efficiently-with-protractor-b8406db9148f) can be found here.